# How can I use wildcards to `cp` a group of files with the AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm having trouble using `*` in the AWS CLI to select a subset of files from a certain bucket.

Adding `*` to the path like this does not seem to work:

`aws s3 cp s3://data/2016-08* .`

Comment: This question is currently [being discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/423124/8239061).

Comment: Please don't attempt to close or reopen this question while it's discussed on meta, it's no use, as people will disagree with the outcome and will close/reopen it again. Better use your limited amount of votes for all the complete garbage we receive daily.

Answer (score 396, accepted):

To download multiple files from an Amazon AWS bucket to your current directory, you can use the `recursive`, `exclude`, and `include` flags. The *order* of the parameters matters.

Example command:

```
aws s3 cp s3://data/ . --recursive --exclude "*" --include "2016-08*"
```

For more information on how to use these filters: *[Use of Exclude and Include Filters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/#use-of-exclude-and-include-filters)*

Comment: I'd like to point out the `--exclude "*"` isn't a typo. *If you don't add it, the include will match anything*. As per the documentation:

Note that, by default, all files are included. This means that providing only an --include filter will not change what files are transferred. --include will only re-include files that have been excluded from an --exclude filter.

If you only want to upload files with a particular extension, you need to first exclude all files, then re-include the files with the particular extension.

Comment: Be aware of the order of exclude and include as well.

Comment: You can also use `sync` for a similar effect, which is recursive by default: `aws s3 sync s3://data/ . --exclude "*" --include "2016-08*"`

Comment: It is a good idea to test "destructive" commands with the `--dryrun` flag to make sure the correct set of object is selected by the wildcard.

Comment: Also good to note that the `--recursive` flag is required. Or it will not work.

Answer (score 89):

**The Order of the Parameters Matters**

The exclude and include should be used in a specific order, We have to first exclude and then include. The vice versa of it will not be successful.

```
aws s3 cp s3://data/ . --recursive  --include "2016-08*" --exclude "*"
```

This will fail because order of the parameters maters in this case. The include is excluded by the `*`.

```
aws s3 cp s3://data/ . --recursive --exclude "*" --include "2016-08*"`
```

This one will work because then we excluded everything, but later we had included the specific directory.

Answer (score 12):

Okay I have to say the example is wrong and should be corrected as follows:

```
aws s3 cp . s3://data/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "2006-08*" --exclude "*/*"
```

The `.` needs to be right after the `cp`. The final `--exclude` is to make sure that nothing is picked up from any subdirectories that are picked up by the `--recursive` (learned that one by mistake...)

This will work for anyone struggling with this by the time they got here.

Comment: this is for copying _from_ your current local current directory _to_ the specified S3 location.  all the other responses is copying _from_ s3 location _to_ your local current directory

Answer (score -2):

If there is an error while using `‘ * ’` you can also use recursive, include, and exclude flags like

`aws s3 cp s3://myfiles/ . --recursive --exclude "*" --include "file*"`